# Complex Formula with Multiple Conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to work out how much time the client has spent out of the system. The rules are I need to use the logout time and subtract it from the next logon time to work out the system out time. The 1st logon of the day has no system out time and the next day it is all reset. I am not sure if I can get a formula to cover all these scenarios.

The formula of C2-0 for row 1 and B3-C2 for Row 2 work for the 1st 2 rows then you get a new client. Then the next day it system out time gets reset and you need to work it out again for the next day like row 1 and 2.

[image]

Comment: Can you just calculate the difference between the system in time and 24 hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((TEXT($B$1:B1,"dd-mm-jjjj")=TEXT(B2,"dd-mm-jjjj"))*($A$1:A1=A2))>0,B2-INDEX($C$1:$C$6,MATCH(1,($A$1:A1=A2)*(TEXT($B$1:B1,"dd-mm-jjjj")=TEXT(B2,"dd-mm-jjjj")),0)),0)
```

Entered as array through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag down...

Note: Change text format to your liking, mine is in Dutch hence why I used "dd-mm-jjjj"